# Show/Hide images using click event of button in angular material

Tags: image, button, angular-material

I'm using angular material, i have two components i.e. Side navbar and toolbar and i want to display two different images based on whether side navbar is closed or opened. If it is open i want the image to be displayed inside it, else on the toolbar.

I would like to know how to show or hide an image on button

```
(click)=drawer.toggle();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the image to both the toolbar and the sidebar, and `*ngIf` to both images to determine whether to render it depending on whether the sidebar is open or closed. The one in the sidebar is:

```
<img *ngIf="sidenav.opened" src="https://angular.io/generated/images/marketing/features/feature-icon.svg" />
```

The `*ngIf="sidenav.opened"` will ensure the image is only rendered if the sidebar is opened.

The image in the toolbar is:

```
<img *ngIf="!sidenav.opened" src="https://angular.io/generated/images/marketing/features/feature-icon.svg" />
```

The `*ngIf="!sidenav.opened"` will ensure the image is only rendered if the sidebar is closed.

When `toggle()` is called on the sidenav, the `opened` property of the sidenav is automatically updated, so anything we bind to that property (i.e. the images) will update accordingly.

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1w67wp?file=app/sidenav-overview-example.html) for a demo. Click the "Toggle Sidebar" button to toggle the sidebar between opened and closed, and the image will display in the toolbar (if the sidebar is closed) and in the sidebar (if the sidebar is open).